# I cant figure out how to make this function execute after the first one is done

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function called chat chattext, which purposes is to write text to a box letter by letter.

```
function chattext(chat) {
  playaudio("talking.mp3");
  document.getElementById("chat").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("chat").innerHTML = "";
  var count = 0;
  function update() {
    console.log(count);
    document.getElementById("chat").innerHTML += `${chat.substring(
      count - 1,
      count
    )}`;

    if (++count < chat.length) {

      setTimeout(update, 50);
    } else {
    }
  }
  update();
}
```

And in another file I execute it like `chattext("hello world")`
which works fine, but if I execute it something after that like
like

```
chattext("hello world")
chattext("hi")
```

it will do both at the same time and output "hhello worl"
[not wanted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3895.png)
so im wondering how can I make it so the 2nd execution of the function will wait for the first to finish?

Comment: maybe you can turn your function in an async function, either by returning a promise or just adding async before your function definition

Comment: not regarding the question but: stop using ``var`` and don't do this: ``++count < chat.length``

Answer (score 1):

As it is, you have no way of knowing when a single invocation of `chattext` has finished, and if you call it twice in succession (while one is still busy), both invocations will "fight" over the text field.

You'll have a better time turning it into an `async` function, which will also mean you'll need an `async` delay function, provided below.

And naturally the function(s) you call that function from will need to be `async` so you can `await` for `chattext`'s completion.

```js
function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function chattext(chat, ms=50) {
  chat = String(chat);
  var el = document.getElementById("chat");
  for(let i = 0; i < chat.length; i++) {
    el.innerHTML += chat[i];
    await delay(ms);
  }
}

async function main() {
  await chattext("Hello, world!\n");
  await delay(1000);
  await chattext("It's a nice day, isn't it?\n\n");
  await delay(1000);
  await chattext("You have nowhere to run.\n", 200);
}

main();
```

```css
#chat {
  background: #333;
  color: pink;
  font-family: monospace;
  white-space: pre;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: 15pt;
  text-shadow: red 1px 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="chat"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to put the words to print into an array and constantly check the array.

```js
const words = [];
let wordIndex = 0;
const display = document.querySelector("div");

setInterval(() => {
  if (words.length) {
    display.innerHTML += words[0][wordIndex++];
    if (wordIndex == words[0].length) {
      words.shift();
      wordIndex = 0;
      display.innerHTML += '<br>';
    }
  }
 }, 100);
  
document.querySelector("button").onclick = () => {
  const txt = document.querySelector("input");
  words.push(txt.value || " ");
  txt.value = "";
};
```

```html
<input type="text"><button>Show</button>
<div></div>
```

You could optimize this by clearing the interval when the list is empty and restarting it when adding a word to an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest restructuring you implementation in the following way:

Create a an empty string or array of characters outside of the function, lets say a global, for simplicity. (adjust to your project).

We'll call that variable `textForChat`.

Make a variable `currChar` that holds the index of the next character we want to type.

Make a function `typeNextChar()` that whenever called, if `currChar` is within `textForChat`'s length,types the character at that position to the chat box and increments the index.

Then, call `setInterval(typeNextChar, 50)`. Which will run `typeNextChar()` every 50 milliseconds (your current rate). So this will type at a speed of 20 chars/second, until it has typed all characters of `textForChat`.

This way, when you want to add more characters, you simply append them to `textForChat`, and they get typed automatically, since the interval we set is still running, and `textForChat`'s content/length has changed because of us adding characters.

You should also add a controller function to initiate/stop the interval timer, when needed.

```
let textForChat = "";
let currChar = 0;
function typeNextChar() {
    if (currChar < textForChat.length) {
        document.getElementById("chat").innerHTML += textForChat.charAt(currChar++);
    }
}
typingTimer = setInterval(typeNextChar, 50);

// Usage - output text does not overlap => solves your issue
textForChat += "Hi!";
textForChat += "Hello World!";
```

Whenever you need to stop typing call `clearInterval(typingTimer)`.
To restart it just do `typingTimer = setInterval(typeNextChar, 50)`